# Iterating over a python array and find mean/min/max for 50 values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mean, numpy-ndarray

I have an array and I want to divide it into subarrays. I need to know the mean/min/max for the first 50 values, then for next and so on. And I want to save mean, min, max in another matrix. At the moment I am solving it this way:

```
np.array([[a[0:50].mean(), a[0:50].min(), a[0:50].max()],
          [a[51:100].mean(), a[51:100].min(), a[51:100].max()],...])
```

a is the matrix.
Now this is working for quite small arrays, but i need it for a much larger array. I was thinking about solving it with a for or while loop but everything I tried failed.

Answer (score 1):

Using [array_split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
a = np.array(range(200))

b = np.array([[x.mean(), x.min(), x.max()] 
              for x in np.array_split(a, a.shape[0]/50)])
```

### Output:

```
>>> b
array([[ 24.5,   0. ,  49. ],
       [ 74.5,  50. ,  99. ],
       [124.5, 100. , 149. ],
       [174.5, 150. , 199. ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the full solution here, but my input which should help.

Basically, get the lenght of the array, split points, then use np.split to separate them.

```py
    # get the length of the array, divide by 50.
    # converting to int so there's no decimals
    fifties = int(len(np.array) / 50)

    # convert this to an array to work through
    fifties = np.arange(fifties)

    # get the split points
    # this could be combined into the command above
    for i in fifties:
        fifties[i] = fifties[i] * 50

    # split the array per 50 into new arrays / dimensions on the array
    newarray = np.split(np.array,fifties)

    # iterate through each new array
    # len(newarray) gives the number of arrays, start at 1, not 0 though

    for i in range(1,len(newarray):
        print('Group '+str(i)+':')
        print(newarray[i].mean())
        print(newarray[i].min())
        print(newarray[i].max())
```

**Output:**

Group 1:
24.5
49
0
Group 2:
74.5
99
50
Group 3:
127.0
154
100

I hope this helps!!